# Using 'either' in place of 'regardless of'

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I know I can say 'Either way,' instead of 'Regardless,', but can I use 'Either ...' in place of 'Regardless of ...' to describe what is unconditional? For example, is this idiomatic compared to the latter one?

> Either which one being a lie, they all sound interesting.

> Regardless of which one being a lie, they all sound interesting.

Comment: No. "Either which one" isn't grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

*Either way* does **not** always mean the same as *regardless*, though they may sometimes be used in a similar context. Neither of your two sentences is idiomatic.

The second one could be written as:

> Regardless of one of them being a lie, they all sound interesting. (Disregarding the fact that one is known to be a lie...)
>
> Regardless of which one is a lie... (It doesn't matter which of them is a lie.)

The first sentence doesn't make sense. You could say:

> One or other of them may be a lie, but, either way, they both sound interesting.